# Spring Upgrade using @RequestBody annotation or @ResponseBody

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to Spring. I want to use `@RequestBody` annotation or `@ResponseBody` annotation instead of using `Model` and `View`.
Following is the method which is currently having Model and View i want to use 
`@ResponseBody` annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/limits", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView  getUserLimits(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,  Authentication authentication) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());

    if(authentication == null){
        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        return null;
    }

    String userid = authentication.getName();

    mv.addObject("limits", Service.getlimitsInfo(userid));
    return mv;

}
```

How do I use the specified annotation without `Model` and `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand, the actual point of @ResponseBody and @RequestBody.

```
@ResponseBody @RequestMapping("/description")
public Description getDescription(@RequestBody UserStats stats){
    return new Description(stats.getFirstName() + " " + stats.getLastname() + " hates wacky wabbits");
}
```

Your method header would look like that :

```
protected  @ReponseBody List<Limit> getUserLimits(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,  @RequestBody Authentication authentication) throws Exception
```

Then you can use this with any javascript library to post data as json, and get them as json as well.

You can also start by reading http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html
There is a section about it.

Hope that's help.